# Write d.ts file for JavaScript that exports a default function and a named export

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Was attempting to write a d.ts file for worker-farm (https://github.com/rvagg/node-worker-farm) However I ran across an issue.

worker-farm does a module.exports like this:

```
module.exports     = farm
module.exports.end = end
```

If I try to do this in typescript such as

```
export function end(workers:any):void;
export =  workerFarm;
```

I receive an error saying I can't mix export types.  Trying to use default seems to not let me export it either.

Is it possible to replicate this in a definition?

Comment: Ever found out how to do it? Might be related to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109027/write-a-declaration-file-for-a-default-export-module

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to use namespaces for this.

Something like:

```
declare function workerFarm(){}

declare namespace workerFarm
{
    export function end( workers: any ): void;
}

export = workerFarm;
```

Look at this example in documentation:
http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-function-d-ts.html

Comment: I know it's been a bit, but thank you, this worked great!