# Write a declaration file for a default export module

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a npm module called RiveScript that usually (in Javascript) gets instantiated that way:

```
var RiveScript = require('rivescript');
var rivescript = new RiveScript();
```

I'm trying to write a declaration file for the module, but am stuck at the first step. Here's what I've written so far:

```
declare module "rivescript" {

    interface RivescriptOptions {
        utf8?: boolean;
    }

    class RiveScript {
        constructor(options?: RivescriptOptions);
    }

    export default RiveScript;
}
```

Then I guess in Typescript I would be using the module this way (*default import*):

```
import RiveScript from 'rivescript';
let rivescript = new RiveScript();
```

However, `tsc` generates this, which is not valid as it references a `default()` function:

```
const rivescript_1 = require('rivescript');
let rivescript = new rivescript_1.default();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You're really close. Instead of using `export default`, you should use `export =`.

**custom-typings/rivescript.d.ts**

```
declare module 'rivescript' {
  class RiveScript {
    constructor()
  }
  export = RiveScript
}
```

**app.js**

```
import RiveScript = require('rivescript');
let rivescript = new RiveScript();
```

For more info on how to write declaration files, you should have a look at the [Typescript Handbook](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/tree/master/pages/declaration%20files). Eg. they have a template for 'exporting modules as a class.

Comment: It works, thanks! 
I'm just confused by the fact that the `import RiveScript = require('rivescript');` syntax doesn't look like a valid ES6 import statement?

Comment: As far as I understand, `import Rivescript from 'rivescript'` should import the default export of Rivescript. However, there is no default export: https://github.com/aichaos/rivescript-js/blob/master/src/rivescript.coffee#L963. For a full overview: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2242

Comment: Seems like `import Rivescript from 'rivescript'` works fine and imports default export at least with the latest Typescript 3.3 I am using.

Comment: @julien_c `import RiveScript = require('rivescript');` is special TS syntax. And yes you will need just `import Rivescript from 'rivescript'` for JS

Answer (score 17):

In case you were looking for a solution applicable to default exported functions:

```js
declare module "my-module" {
  function myFunction(foo: number): string;

  export default myFunction;
}
```

Comment: It clearly doesn't work, see the standard: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require
I.e. the only proper solution for `module.exports = function (){}` is:
```ts
declare module 'my-module' {
function blabla(...): ...;
export = blabla;
```
And then:
```ts
import blabla = require('my-module');
```

Answer (score -1):

**Accepted anwser works well for this question. But I want to give another idea**

if you want to **extends** class, add dynamic method to class at runtime.

you can try (src/plugins/processor.ts)

```
    import server from '../../server'

    declare module "../../server"{
        export default interface server{
            process() // it's a new method of server
        }
    }

    export default class{ //another codes, just for show I create a 'server' instance
        private instance:server
        constructor{
            this.instance = new server()
            this.instance.process() //works
        }
    }
```

in my `server.ts`(src/server.ts),

my default export class signature

```
    export default class Server extends extend implements Startable<void>
```

Because Server is a `default export`, so you can change `server` in `export default interface server` to any valid variable name

for example:

```
export default interface anotherName
```