# How should I do to create my own Typings DefinitelyTyped which have default as class

Tags: typescript, ranking, typing

I want to create my own Typings DefinitelyTyped for Ranking project (https://github.com/maxcnunes/ranking)

I've try some implementation following...

```
declare module 'ranking' {
  interface RankingPlayer {
    position: number
    score: number
    playerId: any
  }

  interface Ranking {
    maxScore: number
    branchFactor: number
    players: any
    find(query);
    findOne(query);
    setScore(player: RankingPlayer);
    addPlayerPoints(player: RankingPlayer);
  }

  interface RankingStatic {
    (config: any): Ranking;
  }

  var ranking: RankingStatic;

  export = ranking;
}
```

When I try with code

```
import Ranking from 'ranking'
...
console.log(Ranking) // This out '[Function: Ranking]'
const ranking = new Ranking({}) // This Error 'Cannot call a class as a function'
```

So I try again with the following codes...

```
declare module 'ranking' {
  interface RankingPlayer {
    position: number
    score: number
    playerId: any
  }

  export default class Ranking {
    maxScore: number
    branchFactor: number
    players: any
    constructor(config: any)
    find(query)
    findOne(query)
    setScore(player: RankingPlayer)
    addPlayerPoints(player: RankingPlayer)
  }
}
```

And try with code

```
import Ranking from 'ranking'
...
console.log(Ranking) // This out 'undefined'
const ranking = new Ranking({}) // This Error 'ranking_1.default is not a constructor'
```

Don't know what should do to implement this :(

Comment: I think this is not a problem with your typing, rather than your build process. Can you add that please?

Comment: @SebastianSebald I don't know what is build process?

Comment: Since your have to transpile your TypeScript code to JavaScript I guess you have some sort of process to do that. Or is the error shown in your IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `Ranking` is a class, so I would also define it as such:

**custom-typings/ranking.d.ts**

```
declare module 'ranking' {
  class Ranking {
    constructor(options?: {})
  }
  export = Ranking
}
```

Then you can just call it like:

**app.ts**

```
import Ranking = require('ranking');
const ranking = new Ranking({
  maxScore: 1000000,
  branchFactor: 1000
});
```

Notice the use of `import Ranking = require('ranking')` instead of `import Ranking from 'ranking'`. For the full discussion on the difference, I refer you to [this github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2242).

Also I answered a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109027/write-a-declaration-file-for-a-default-export-module/), you might want to check out.