# How do I write a Typescript definition file for a JavaScript library written like the following?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I have an old JavaScript library that I wrote to work with `AMD` and `CommonJS`. I forgot the original source which influenced me to write the library in this way, but my JavaScript library is written in the following pattern.

```
(function(window) {
 'use strict';

 function getLib() {
  var mylib = {};
  mylib.getSomething = function() {
   return 'x';
  }
  mylib.getCar = function(make, model, year) {
   return {
    make: make,
    model: model,
    year: year
   };
  }
  return mylib;
 }

 if(typeof module === 'object' && module && typeof module.exports === 'object') {
    module.exports = getLib();
  } else {
    if(typeof(mylib) === 'undefined') {
      window.mylib = getLib();
    }

    if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
      define('mylib', [], getLib());
    }
  }
})(this);
```

How do I write a type definition `d.ts` file for this JavaScript library?

I attempted to write a `d.ts` as follows, but it does not work. In my Angular app, I put the following file `node_modules/@types/mylib/index.d.ts`.

```
interface Car {
 make: string;
 model: string;
 year: number;
}

interface MyLib {
 getSomething(): string;
 getCar(make: string, model: string, year: number): Car;
}

declare module "mylib" {
 export let mylib: MyLib
}
```

In my controller, I simply try to import the library and debug it to the console, but get `undefined`.

```
import {mylib} from 'mylib'; //IDE doesn't complain, seems to find the type def

export class MyPage {
 constructor() {
  console.log(mylib); //undefined
  console.log(mylib.getCar('ford', 'f150', 2018)); //code won't reach here
 }
}
```

Note that the JavaScript package `mylib` is not on `NPM` but a private repository and I have already installed it (e.g. `npm install mylib --save`) to `node_modules/mylib`. I mention this because I am not sure where the type def file should go.

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

Per the advice below, I've modified my `d.ts` file to look like the following and placed it in `mylib/index.d.ts`.

```
declare module "mylib" {
    let mylib: MyLib;
    export = mylib; 
}
```

Now, I can import the library in two ways. First way.

```
import mylib from 'mylib';
```

Second way.

```
import * as mylib from 'mylib';
```

In VS Code, the IDE, there are no complaints (no red lines hinting at problems). Furthermore, I've modified `tsconfig.json` to look like the following.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2015.promise",
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

When I run `ng build`, I see the message below.

```
ERROR in node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(3268,88): error TS2344: Type 'SVGElementTagNameMap[K]' does not satisfy the constraint 'Node'.
  Type 'SVGSVGElement | SVGCircleElement | SVGClipPathElement | SVGDefsElement | SVGDescElement | SVGElli...' is not assignable to type 'Node'.
    Type 'SVGFEColorMatrixElement' is not assignable to type 'Node'.
      Types of property 'values' are incompatible.
        Type 'SVGAnimatedNumberList' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
          Property 'includes' is missing in type 'SVGAnimatedNumberList'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(3626,85): error TS2344: Type 'SVGElementTagNameMap[K]' does not satisfy the constraint 'Node'.
  Type 'SVGSVGElement | SVGCircleElement | SVGClipPathElement | SVGDefsElement | SVGDescElement | SVGElli...' is not assignable to type 'Node'.
    Type 'SVGFEColorMatrixElement' is not assignable to type 'Node'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(10405,11): error TS2430: Interface 'SVGFEColorMatrixElement' incorrectly extends interface 'SVGElement'.
  Types of property 'values' are incompatible.
    Type 'SVGAnimatedNumberList' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(14172,86): error TS2344: Type 'SVGElementTagNameMap[K]' does not satisfy the constraint 'Node'.
  Type 'SVGSVGElement | SVGCircleElement | SVGClipPathElement | SVGDefsElement | SVGDescElement | SVGElli...' is not assignable to type 'Node'.
    Type 'SVGFEColorMatrixElement' is not assignable to type 'Node'.
```

The "interesting" thing is that if I comment out the `import` then run `ng build` or `ng serve`, the compile error goes away. While the app is in live reload mode, I can simply uncomment the `import`, and though the compile error shows up, I can still use all the features of the library in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned NPM, I'm assuming that the code which uses `mylib` is using CommonJS module resolution, and you are running it in node (or you are using something like webpack).

Then, this export variant is in effect:

```
module.exports = getLib();
```

This exports mylib object as a whole, and does not introduce anything named `mylib`, so the named import

```
import {mylib} from 'mylib'.
```

is undefined at runtime.

How to consume this kind of export in TypeScript is complicated, [but starting from TypeScript 2.7](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#support-for-import-d-from-cjs-form-commonjs-modules-with---esmoduleinterop), the way that usually works is

1. write type declaration using [export assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109027/write-a-declaration-file-for-a-default-export-module)

   ```
   declare module "mylib" {
       let mylib: MyLib;
       export = mylib; 
   }
   ```
2. compile with `--module=commonjs` and `--esModuleInterop=true`
3. import it as if it was default export

   ```
   import mylib from 'mylib';
   ```

**UPDATE**

To avoid name conflicts in global scope, it would be better to have all the types from `mylib` declared within `mylib` module scope, like this

```
declare module "mylib" {

    export interface Car {
        make: string;
        model: string;
        year: number;
    }

    export interface MyLib {
        getSomething(): string;
        getCar(make: string, model: string, year: number): Car;
    }

    export let mylib: MyLib
}
```

But then, you will have to import these types explicitly in every module that needs them:

```
import mylib from 'mylib';

import {Car, MyLib} from 'mylib';
```

Comment: I followed your advice and modified `tsconfig.json` to set the `module` and `esModuleInterop` to the values you specified above. However, when I type in `ng build`, I get a compile error: `ERROR in node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(3268,88): error TS2344: Type 'SVGElementTagNameMap[K]' does not satisfy the constraint 'Node'.` Note that I have placed `index.d.ts` at the root of the project, and `import mylib from 'mylib'` does not show any errors in the IDE (VS Code). Any ideas?

Comment: Something interest to observe. If I comment out the import statement and run `ng serve` the compile error goes away. While the server is running from `ng serve`, if I uncomment the import statements, the compile error shows up in the console, however, I can still use my library's code completely! This observation leads me to believe that the problem is with the compile configuration. Not sure how to fix that.

Comment: Is there by any chance some interface or type named `Node` in mylib?

Comment: You are right! There is an interface named `Node` (this is a graph library with Node, Edge, Graph). Let me see if I can tinker with that.

Comment: Then it would be better to have all the interfaces from `mylib` declared within the `declare module { .. }` scope, not as globals, to avoid interfering with other global types. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

In your type declaration file, the `getSomething` and `getCar` functions are members of a named export named `mylib`, but in the implementation, `getSomething` and `getCar` are themselves exports of the module.  The cleanest way to write the declaration file would be like this:

```
declare module "mylib" {
 export function getSomething(): string;
 export function getCar(make: string, model: string, year: number): Car;
}
```

(Using an export assignment as artem said is another option.)

Side note: It's inadvisable to create a file at `node_modules/@types/mylib/index.d.ts` manually because package management tools such as npm and yarn expect to be in control of the entire `node_modules` directory.  Instead, you can add the declaration file to the original `mylib` package or publish an actual `@types/mylib` package to your private repository.  Or if you want to use the type declarations only in this Angular app, you can put the `index.d.ts` file in its own directory in the Angular app and either (1) set the [`baseUrl` and `paths` options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) so that module resolution of `mylib` finds your file or (2) create a `package.json` file for your type declaration and register it as a dependency in your main `package.json` using a relative path.

Comment: Please let me clarify; are you saying one approach could be to simply add the type definition file to the root of `mylib`? So upon `npm install mylib --save` it will end up in `node_modules/mylib/index.d.ts`? And then from there I may import as `import mylib from 'mylib'`?

Comment: Yes, that should work in terms of finding the declaration file.  A separate issue is that the default import will only work if you enable `esModuleInterop` according to artem's answer.  If you want to import the entire module, I would suggest instead using `import * as mylib from 'mylib';`.  That works regardless of `esModuleInterop`.